# Directed Graph in Haskell

Tags: haskell-platform, template-haskell, haskell, haskell-mode

I am now struggling with Haskell. Even, I have some experience with imperative languages, with OOP, but Haskell seems to be different from them. I under-evaluated Haskell, and think learning a new language is not a problem with me. However, after spending a whole week with many new concepts (typeclass, functors, applicative, monoids, monads... reading all 14 chapters from this [learnyouahaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)), I noticed that they make me so confused, don't know how to start writing a programme with Haskell. Some experts say that it take you a few months to master Haskell. But I have only two weeks to finish a big project.

1) So my first question is how to learn Haskell

2) When I need to use applicative functors, and when I need to use monads?

3) My project is to handle with directed graph based on many presentations:

- adjacency matrix
- binary search tree

I am quite a Haskell newbie, so don't know where I can start with directed graph in Haskell? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest you remove your intro and stick with your third question which is more specific.

Comment: Since Haskell is functional, you'll have to put your recursive hat on. How well do you understand recursion and lists?

Comment: About recursion, and lists I understand well enough. I mean I did almost examples in 14 chapters of the tutorial. But for me, to start with a big project, still makes me confused of how and when to apply functors, applicative functors, monads, ... @gawi: I agree that it's better to start with the 3-rd question, because it's more specific. Just curious about how you guys master Haskell.

Comment: Is Haskell required for this project? Haskell *is* quite different from OO languages; if you have not had any experience with the functional programming paradigm then you should give yourself more time to learn, and if possible, choose a more familiar language for the impending deadline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question (how to learn Haskell), I'd say that you need to actually code in it. It sounds like you read the many chapters of Learn You A Haskell, but they made your head swim. Go a little slower, and -- more importantly -- follow along, by typing and evaluating the code. You say that you "don't know where to start writing a program in Haskell." The practice of actually writing and executing the examples will be exactly what you need to get a feel for how the code works, and where to start.

You're probably not quite prepared for the answer to your second question (when to use `Monad` and when to use `Applicative`) -- work through LYAH, though, and you'll definitely know when to use each.

As far as directed graphs specifically, [this is a good resource](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201596040) (the Amazon reviews aren't very good, but I think it's a great introduction to the concepts of graphs and abstract data types in Haskell).

Good luck - Haskell is well worth the struggle!